# Shortcut key to login at XP Welcome Screen?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, login, login-screen

Can the login sequence at the XP Welcome Screen be initiated by the keyboard, or does the user have to click on the username icon?

Note: the double <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Del</kbd> trick does not work if a user is already logged in, so please don't suggest that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Simply use the up and down arrows to select the user account, type in the password if required, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:** Based on the feedback from the poster, you should be able to just hit `Tab` to move to the user you want to select and then press `Enter`.

If I'm understanding what you mean correctly (disabling the Welcome Screen where you click the username and then enter their password), you'd want to go into the Windows account preferences and disable the Welcome Screen.

All you need to do is:

1. Select *Start* > *Control Panel* > *Open User Accounts*
2. Click *Change the way users log on or off*
3. Click to clear the *Use the Welcome screen check
   box*

*Stolen from: http://www.helpwithwindows.com/WindowsXP/start-05.html

Comment: No, I don't want to disable the Welcome Screen. What I want is to be able to login without having to mouse click on the username icon on the Welcome Screen. I would rather trigger this action by a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Oh, then why not try pressing Tab until the username is selected then pressing enter?